# Visual Studio 2019 Remove Virtual Vertical Added Blank Lines

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

When I was previously using Visual Studio 2017 -- I didn't have these inserted virtual vertical lines in my code.

They are slightly bothering me, and I would like to get rid of them.

how do I do so?

[image]

Picture above shows this blank space that gets inserted by VS.  I've tried googling / looking through Text Editor settings, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [CodeLens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2019) option. To toggle on/off, go Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages:

[image]

FWIW, though the lines may be blank right now, I've found them pretty useful in tracing dependencies, seeing last/most recent changes to a particular method, etc. You might get used to it, once those (now empty) lines start showing you valuable details.

Comment: I have the Community Edition Version -- And it does not show any dependencies in it.  So it is quite useless

Comment: Only thing it does show -- *sometimes* is references -- yes... But overall it is annoying it just being empty majority of the time.

Comment: Can't speak to the CE of VSTO, but I meant "references" when I said "dependencies". It's neat to see what other parts of your code are calling a particular method/etc. The other stuff is individually configurable, and e.g., the timeline appears to be linked to TFVC or Git, so if your code isn't under one or the other of those source control, it won't show that detail.